# Laravel sail - accented search term queries not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, non-ascii-characters, laravel-sail

I am using Laravel Sail and when performing back-end queries, the accented term searches not working, as, for example "éz" becomes "ez". I checked php.ini, and it is UTF-8, so the problem does not come from here. I think it is because of MYSQL character settings, but in TablePlus, the character set is: `utf8mb4`, and collation is: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

An example of the query is (simplified):

```
Client::query()->where("disposition", "LIKE", "%" . "éz" . "%")
```

Instead of "éz", "ez" is used when querying the table.

Comment: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is accent-insensitive. If you want your comparisons to be accent-sensitive then you need to change collation - https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-accent-and-case-sensitive-collations-for-utf8mb4/

Comment: Oh, I thought it is accent-sensitive. Thank you! I am trying.

Comment: You can use `SHOW COLLATION LIKE '%utf8mb4%\_as\_%';` to see which accent-sensitive collations are available to you.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: mysql/mysql-server:8.0